# jQuery mouse in div

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I've been googling and looking on Stackoverflow but I can't find the answer.

Is there an easy way to know if a mouse is *in* a div, or not (hovering)?

The only solution I could come up with is:

```
$("#somediv").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).data("in", true);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeData("in");
});
```

and then to check:

```
if ($("#somediv").data("in")) {
   ...
}
```

Is there really no easier way?

Comment: Can't you put your code directly into the hover callback functions?

Comment: no, i need the status. mouse is in, or not. This is for a flyout-dialog. i hover on an icon, and the dialog opens. when i hover out the icon, and hover IN the dialog, i need to stop the closing event of the hover-out of the icon, so i need to know, is the mouse IN the dialog or not. if yes: dont close. if not: close.

Comment: I see. Well, in this case your solution is the only one that comes to my mind too, as of now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track the mouse's position:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  x = e.pageX; // globals, but you could tie them to a namespace or whatever
  y = e.pageY;
});
```

The advantage here is that you needn't worry about binding/unbinding a whole bunch of hover events for a whole lot of different elements. You can then ask (at any given time, as opposed to my second solution) whether or not the mouse position falls within any element's coordinates.

You might prefer to bind it not in an anonymous function so that you can unbind it (for performance reasons and the like).

One drawback with this approach is that `mousemove()` only fires when you move the mouse although if i scroll with the keyboard the mouse position in the document has changed without the event firing. This  does **not** apply to your solution (at least not with my primitive jsFiddle test in FF). You can fix this by updating the coords with a `keypress` event, or something similar, although that makes things complicated, and you want simple.

Alternatively, you can use the event object given to events and ask the mouse's position directly from your relevant event. So lets say you only needed to check whether or not the mouse was in a given div when a simple event happened, say the user triggered a `mouseup()` somewhere, then you just refer to the event object you have:

```
someDiv.mouseup(function(e){

  // ...
  // other stuff
  // ...

  if (ns.isMouseInDiv(someOtherDiv, e))
     foo();

});
```

Again, you save having to bind to every object you want to check.

Comment: i did read about this kind of way but it does look very complicated and might degrade performance. I dont really need to bind a lot now either. all the flyouts have the same class and the icons too. so my code is very clean and simple. thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Stefanvds, it's very simple, you can see that the second solution is 1 function call, which can be written in about 3 lines of code. be aware that performance isn't measured purely by length of code, if you have many flyouts even with one line `$('.flyouts').hover()` you bind that behaviour to many elements whereas my second solution requires no binding whatsoever. in short, my second solution is more optimal than your code in my opinion, but it's totally your choice whether it is appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just set a var onmouseover, and unset it onmouseout?

Comment: That's essentially what he's doing with the `hover` ;)

Comment: this should work not just for 1 div, but for many divs, my code is pseudo :) a var wouldnt work.

Comment: Well, you can create an array with div names as keys... but I fear my knowledge of jQuery is insufficient here.

Comment: why would that be better than using the data attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In the hover-out event handler of the icon then, you could perhaps check whether the dialog div has the :hover pseudo class. Like:

```
if($("#dialog:hover").length)){
    ...
}
```

Haven't tried it though... Did I at least get what you're trying to do? ;)

UPDATE: try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cpak/MBJ6Q/

As mentioned in comment below, requires mouse to go directly from the icon to the dialog.

Comment: This would probably not work if there's any space between the icon and the menu though, since the hover-out event would fire before the mouse gets on top of the menu div.

Comment: `dialog.is(":visible")` works but `dialog.is(":hover")` doesnt work :) so `:hover` doesnt work :) nice try though!

Comment: OK, too bad. Check the Fiddle though, got something similar working there at least.